# why is webpack generated code getting executed twice?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, duplicates, execution

The browser console shows that the code is executed twice:

```
    [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
    index.ts:1 WebPack - Learn - begin
    log.js:24 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
    index.ts:1 WebPack - Learn - begin
    2index.js:519 [webpack-dev-server] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
    2index.js:519 [webpack-dev-server] Live Reloading enabled.
```

As you can see, the "WebPack - Learn - begin" is executed twice.

webpack.config.js

```
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
    const path = require('path');
    
    module.exports = {
        entry: './src/index.ts',
        devtool: 'inline-source-map',
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    use: 'ts-loader',
                    exclude: /node_modules/
                }
            ]
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.tsx']
        },
        output: {
            filename: 'bundle.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
        },
    
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.html")
            })
        ],
    
        devServer: {
            static: './dist'
        }
    };
```

tsconfig.json

```
    {
        "compilerOptions": {
            "outDir": "./dist/",
            "noImplicitAny": true,
            "module": "es6",
            "moduleResolution": "node",
            "sourceMap": true,
            "target": "es6",
            "typeRoots": [
                "node_modules/@types"
            ],
            "lib": [
                "es2017",
                "dom"
            ]
        }
    }
```

index.ts

```
    console.log("WebPack - Learn - begin")
```

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>WebPack - Learn</title>
    
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Arial';
                background: #ececec;
            }
    
            ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                padding: 20px;
            }
    
            li {
                padding: 20px;
                background: white;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <ul id="output"></ul>
    
        <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

package.json

```
    {
      "name": "TestWebPackServer02",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "https://www.valentinog.com/blog/webpack/",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
        "start": "webpack serve --mode development --open"
      },
      "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/xyz/TestWebPackServer02.git"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/xyz/TestWebPackServer02/issues"
      },
      "homepage": "https://github.com/xyz/TestWebPackServer02#readme",
      "devDependencies": {
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
        "rxjs": "^7.3.0",
        "ts-loader": "^9.2.5",
        "typescript": "^4.4.3",
        "webpack": "^5.52.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.2.1"
      }
    }
```

stackOverflow complained that my post contained mostly code and wanted some more details. So, I'm adding this text at the bottom to satisfy stackOverflow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is that really all of your code, or could it be that within your code you import a module twice with slightly different typing?
As an example:

```
import {myFunc} from './myScriptFile.js';
```

versus

```
import {myFunc} from './myScriptFile';
```

I had a case where an `import` statement that was written without file extension caused the code outside the functions present on that file to be loaded and executed twice.

```
// myScriptFile.js
import * as MYCLASS from './myClass.js';
function myFunc(){
  // Do whatever...
}
export {myFunc};

// This code is executed when the script file is loaded
console.log("Start setup");
let myVar = new MYCLASS.MyClass();
```

Resulted in following output:

```
Start setup    myScriptFile.js:9
Start setup    myScriptFile:9
```

This because myScriptFile was once imported in HTML with a script tag `<script src="./myScriptFile.js" type = "module"></script>` and once was referenced within the 'myClass.js' file, but this time without file extension.

Comment: Thank you for answering but that is my entire code